# Doctrine: row too large when submitting

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a class **Person** with about 100 fields.

recently i added a new field:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\VenderBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_vendor_person")
 */
class Person
{
    ....

    /**
     * My new property
     *
     * @var array $references
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="references", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $references;
```

The form type has been updated accordingly:

```
class PersonInvitationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $context;

    /**
     * PersonNewType constructor.
     * @param AuthorizationChecker $securityContext
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $securityContext)
    {
        $this->context = $securityContext;

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('references', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => Referencese::class,
                'label' => 'References',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'prototype_name' => 'references__name__',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
```

But now I am getting the following error when submitting a form containing almost all fields of class Person:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE my_vendor_person 
SET references = ? WHERE id = ?' with params 
["a:1:{s:7:\"myProperty0\";a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:7:\"my name\";s:6:\"location\";
s:9:\"my location\";s:5:\"phone\";s:8:\"90898978978\";s:5:\"email\";
s:17:\"myemail@gmail.com\";}}", 765]:
```

Below that, the following is stated:

```
QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large 
(> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or 
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored 
inline.
```

The form contains more fields of type array which contain more information then the above example. someone has an idea of what is happening here? Am Running Symfony 3.

**UPDATE:**

please find a pastbin of the dev.log here: http://pastebin.com/0qLm60x7

**SECOND UPDATE:**

please find the `create table` statement here: http://pastebin.com/PFy5jAbx

Comment: It would appear that you are attempting to insert a string into a column whose size is smaller than the string you are sending. Re-check the size of each column and make sure you are not exceeding any limit.

Comment: unfortunately not so. kindly see the annotations, where type has been set to array. in the database the column is of type "longtext", which was set automatically by doctrine.

Comment: I would suggest you add to your question (edit) two things: (1) The `create table` statement, and (2) the `UPDATE` statement being received by the DBMS (what is being sent to the `execute` command).

Comment: Are you able to post the "full" var/logs/dev.log when you do the submit of the form to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for us to look at? I suspect the array is larger than you think.

Comment: Looking at all the possible types for doctrine2, all the array based ones default to using the text type, and no option to change that. The only way I can think of is manually changing the field yourself to be blob, but then if you use the CLI to update your database when developing it'll likely revert it which is not great.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk: I have added a pastebin showing the log when the form is submitted.

Comment: @FDavidov, the update statement is already in the question I believe.

Comment: I agree with @FDavidov 's comments apfz. Can you please edit your post to include the `create table` statement for the table "my_vendor_person"? This might help solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Alvin Bunk, I have added a pastebin for the `create table` statement. thanks for your support so far.

Comment: I see a lot of this: **[2016-09-02 07:00:08] translation.DEBUG: Translation use fallback catalogue. {"id":"The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.","domain":"validators","locale":"en_IN"} []** in the logs. I wonder if that has something to do with the problem? Seems to indicate a translation problem. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Also, I only see errors referring to the column "references_professional". i wonder if you could comment out the particular code that just uses this column and see if that points to the real problem.

Comment: @apfz, I just had a look at what you included in pastebin and, frankly, it is a little bit upsetting to see that you haven't put any efforts to make the reading easy (I mean, the reading by people that is trying to help you). Too much irrelevant information and create table statement as raw text. Sorry, but I will not invest any additional effort on this question.

Comment: @FDavidov. Sorry, I don't know how to display it otherwise.